# What is sludge metal?

Tags: identify-this-genre

I love the Melvins and Mastodon and I thought they were both Alternative Metal. But I found they were labelled as Sludge Metal and in some records Stoner Rock?

I tried wiki but didn't get it. What are these weird named genres?

Comment: I love both the Bands and IMO Melvins is very underrated band.

Comment: I would say listen to a band called Crowbar, a really good sludge metal band. Very distorted guitars and rough vocals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Sludge Metal

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sludge_metal):

> Sludge metal is an extreme genre of music that melds elements of **doom metal and hardcore punk**, and sometimes Southern rock. Sludge metal is typically harsh and abrasive, often featuring **shouted or screamed vocals, heavily distorted instruments and sharply contrasting tempos**. While the style was anticipated by the Melvins from Washington, many of its earliest pioneers were from the city of New Orleans.

The albums [Bullhead](https://www.discogs.com/en/Melvins-Bullhead/master/21243) and [Stag](https://www.discogs.com/en/Melvins-Stag/master/50785) from the Melvins and [Once More 'Round the Sun](https://www.discogs.com/en/Mastodon-Once-More-Round-The-Sun/master/701106) from Mastodon are classified in Sludgs Metal genre.

You can see other Sludge Metal suggestions [here](https://www.discogs.com/en/style/sludge+metal).

### Stoner Rock

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stoner_rock):

> Stoner rock is a rock music fusion genre that combines elements of **heavy metal** and/or **doom metal** with **psychedelic rock and acid rock**. The name references cannabis consumption. Stoner rock is typically **slow-to-mid tempo and features a heavily distorted, groove

The album [Crack the Skye](https://www.discogs.com/en/Mastodon-Crack-The-Skye/master/2938) by Mastodon is classified as Stoner Rock.

Other Stoner Rock suggestions [here](https://www.discogs.com/en/style/stoner+rock).

Comment: Hey do the songs "Night Goat" and "Hooch" , "Blood and Thunder" considered sludge

Comment: Consider the first two Baroness LPs.  Also YOB's work.  Also Windhand.  These are good examples of Sludge Rock.  (YOB is more Doom Rock, but it can get sludgy)